# upgrading server from 16.04.7 to 18.04 fails after Third party sources disabled

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have checked similar issues and tried them with no avail. I have changed the sources from just archive to different countries.

```
Updating repository information

To continue please press [ENTER]

Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information

After updating your package information, the essential package
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list
for the current list of configured software sources.
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade
again later.


Restoring original system state

Aborting
      g package lists... 3%
*** Collecting problem information

The collected information can be sent to the developers to improve the
application. This might take a few minutes.
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
sources.list is just 
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

There isn't anything in /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory. I don't understand why running

```
sudo -E do-release-upgrade
```

is failing..
I'm not sure where the failing information is being saved as /var/log/apt isn't updated or any other obvious log. Any help or direction.

EDIT
Found the logs. /var/log/dist-upgrade
Clock was off about 20 min so they were not obvious.

```
2021-02-07 22:23:02,900 DEBUG Foreign:
2021-02-07 22:23:02,900 DEBUG Obsolete:
2021-02-07 22:23:02,901 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2021-02-07 22:23:02,928 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2021-02-07 22:23:02,928 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2021-02-07 22:23:02,928 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2021-02-07 22:23:02,931 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2021-02-07 22:23:02,933 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,933 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
2021-02-07 22:23:02,933 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release
2021-02-07 22:23:02,933 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release' q='' f=''
2021-02-07 22:23:02,937 DEBUG error from httplib: '<urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,937 DEBUG entry '# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,937 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,937 DEBUG entry '# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG entry '# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG entry '# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG entry '# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG entry '# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG entry '# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,938 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,939 DEBUG entry '# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,939 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,939 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
2021-02-07 22:23:02,939 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release
2021-02-07 22:23:02,939 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.canonical.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release' q='' f=''
2021-02-07 22:23:02,940 DEBUG error from httplib: '<urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,940 DEBUG entry '# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:02,940 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner'
2021-02-07 22:23:02,940 DEBUG entry '# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner' was disabled (no Release file)
2021-02-07 22:23:04,594 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2021-02-07 22:23:04,597 DEBUG openCache()
2021-02-07 22:23:04,698 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 796
2021-02-07 22:23:04,699 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2021-02-07 22:23:04,699 ERROR No 'ubuntu-minimal' available/downloadable after sources.list rewrite+update
2021-02-07 22:23:04,699 ERROR 'ubuntu-minimal' was not downloadable
2021-02-07 22:23:04,702 DEBUG abort called
2021-02-07 22:23:04,702 DEBUG openCache()
2021-02-07 22:23:06,995 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 92695
```

Remarked out the archive.canonical.com sources but still seeing `error from httplib: 'urlopen erro Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>'` which is only happening with the upgrade. I was able to download and install ntp without issue.

Comment: Checked your used mirror; https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de-archive looks okay, I've never used the -E with a `do-release-upgrade`, nor is it mentioned in upgrade instructions (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/18.04.2)

Comment: Ok. Found the logs. System time was off by about 20 mins.

Comment: the -E is for sudo (preserve Environment) since I have some proxy settings that need to be preserved

Comment: hmm. Might need to double check the proxy settings...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have a proxy setting for both http and https. Apparently http doesn't like being forced to use https....

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "https://web-1a:3163";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://web-1a:3163";
```

Once I fixdd the http proxy, all works again.